# Remote monitoring of JBoss from Microsoft Operations Manager (MOM)

Tags: monitoring, jboss, mom, jmx

I'd like to monitor various JMX properties and events from Java web applications running in JBoss Application Server (version 4.0) on Windows. I need to get this information into Microsoft Operations Manager (MOM) in order to raise alerts based on appropriate criteria.

What are the options for getting the data from one to the other?  The only possibility that I can come up with is JMX -> SNMP -> WMI -> MOM, but this seems more convoluted than it should be.

I'm open to all options, paid or free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you upgrde to SCOM 2007.  Interop gets a whole lot easier on that platform.  With SCOM you can monitor JMX directly.  See [Introduction to SCOM 2007 Supported Platforms Cross Platform Extensions features](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/3/F33D91DF-D6E3-442A-9E20-5A39C82111FD/Managing_Your_Enterprise/Bobby_Monitoring_UNIX_Linux.pdf).  While there might be other options for MOM available.  If I was going to spend a dime on a tool to enhance MOM, the upgrade would be where I spend it.

Bridgways MP beta is [here](http://www.bridgeways.ca/bw_management-pack-beta-program-signup_form.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try ManageEngine Applications Manager. It offers JMX monitoring and definitely should have some way of sending info to MOM.